# Preciso modificar o css de um radio button md-radio-button via jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Colegas, estou tentando modificar o `css` de um `md-radio-button` via `jQuery` porém não estou conseguindo.

```
<md-radio-button id="radio_letter" style="margin: 2px!important" ng-click="changeCorrectAlternative(command.key, alternative.key)" ng-repeat="alternative in command.alternative_set" ng-value="alternative.key">
    <md-item style="margin:-21px;text-align:center;">
        {{ ORDER_TO_LETTER[alternative.order-1] }}
    </md-item>
</md-radio-button>
```

Jquery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#radio_letter').each(function(){
        $(this).css('width','21px');
        $(this).css('height','21px');
    });
});
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Pode postar o Controller do angular ?

Comment: Por que exatamente você precisa mudar através de `jQuery`? Não pode ser feito direto com uma classe `css` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode tentar chamar o seu jquery pela diretiva ng-init. Se não funcionar, faça uma chamada a sua função JQuery de dentro do controller utilizando o serviço `$window` e `$timeout`

Cria uma funçã ode ajuste no escopo global (window)

```
function adjust() { 
      jQuery('#radio_letter').css({ 'width':'21px', 'height':'21px'});
});
```

Tente:

```
<md-radio-button ng-init="window.adjust()" ...
```

Ou pelo Controller:

```
app.controller('MeuController', function($window, $timeout) { 
     $timeout($window.adjust, 50);
});
```

Comment: Valeu Rogério Foi de prima. Funcionou que foi uma blz ! obrigado